# Simple continued fraction of Freiman's constant

Tags: nt.number-theory, continued-fractions

The quadratic irrational $\frac{2221564096+283748\sqrt{462}}{491993569}$ is known as **Freiman's constant** and arises in the theory of continued fractions.  I'm curious as to its simple continued fraction expansion, which, of course, is eventually periodic.  Specifically, I'm wondering what the length $k$ of the initial part is, as well as the length $n$ of its period.  With Mathematica, I compute the first 15000 terms and don't see a repetition yet.  Here is the Mathematica code:

ContinuedFraction[(2221564096+283748*Sqrt[462])/491993569,15000]

The continued fraction expansion is $[4;1,1,8,2,14,2,2,1,12,117,1,1,7,16,\ldots]$, but that sequence does not appear in the OEIS.  I have a suspicion that $k$ and $n$ are very large.  Is computing them feasible?  If not, can one provide estimates?

One can ask, more naturally, for the length of the period of an $\alpha \in \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{462})$ with Markov constant equal to Freiman's constant.  What is such an $\alpha$, and what is the period of its continued fraction?

I can't find Freiman's paper (in Russian) anywhere, and I'm unable to find any information about these questions in the literature.

EDIT: Given @JackHuizenga's Mathematica computations noted in the comments, all that is left to answer is to find an $\alpha$ with Markov constant equal to Freiman's constant, and to calculate its continued fraction expansion.

Comment: The following command runs quickly in Mathematica:  Sort[DeleteDuplicates[
  ContinuedFraction[(2221564096 + 283748*Sqrt[462])/491993569, 
   50000]]].  By changing the number of terms, it appears that there are still new denominators in the continued fraction appearing somewhere between the 50,000th and 100,000th term, but there are no additional denominators appearing by the 1,000,000th term.  This seems like strong evidence the repetition starts happening somewhere around the 100,000th term.  Presumably it is straightforward to find the exact k and n with Mathematica.

Comment: Taking one of the terms in particular, the integer 24249 appears at positions 4510, 71264, 138018, etc., so presumably $n = 66754$ and $k<4510$.

Comment: By printing the kth and (k+66754)th terms for the first 100 k, I am convinced that the sequence starts repeating at term 6, the 14.  So the fraction is $[4;1;1,8,2,\overline{14,2,2,1,12,\ldots,1,72,1,1}]$ with the repeating part having length 66754.

Comment: That could be checked using FromContinuedFraction[{4,1,1,8,2,{14,2,2,1,12,...}}]

Comment: OK yes, running L = Drop[Take[
    ContinuedFraction[(2221564096 + 283748*Sqrt[462])/491993569, 
     1000000], 66759], 5];
FromContinuedFraction[{4, 1, 1, 8, 2, L}] reproduces the constant!

Comment: The periodic part is $(5687655 + 283748 \cdot462^{1/2})/816983$.  I was going to do it that way!